# Anonymous access to icCube exported permanent link

Tags: iccube-reporting

I am using icCube version 5.2 Community Edition.

I created a schema + report as admin, and it all works ok. Then I am trying to provide access to this report from a web application deployed into Tomcat 7. But ideally, I would like this to be done without icCube requesting the user for authentication.

I tried so far to save the report under anonymous, but that did not work as icCube still requires authentication. icCube server is deployed on a secured server so I could do without its integrated authentication process as well if that makes things easier.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

The ability to add customer authentication and or authorization is part of the Enterprise features.